# I want to export pdf file in browser so that i can use events on it content

Tags: javascript, pdf, mouseevent

I'm using pdf.js (library for JS) to display pdf file in browser and use mouseover event on some of my words. However pdf is displayed as canvas (image) and if I use getTextContent function, order of words complitely messes up.
Here is code I found in github to display pdf

```
const url = '../docs/pdf.pdf';

let pdfDoc = null,
  pageNum = 1,
  pageIsRendering = false,
  pageNumIsPending = null;

const scale = 1.5,
  canvas = document.querySelector('#pdf-render'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Render the page
const renderPage = num => {
  pageIsRendering = true;

  // Get page
  pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(page => {
    // Set scale
    const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale });
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;

    const renderCtx = {
      canvasContext: ctx,
      viewport
    };

    page.render(renderCtx).promise.then(() => {
      pageIsRendering = false;

      if (pageNumIsPending !== null) {
        renderPage(pageNumIsPending);
        pageNumIsPending = null;
      }
    });

    // Get text content of the page
    page.getTextContent().then(textContent => {
      // Clear existing text
      const textLayer = document.querySelector('.text-layer');
      if (textLayer) {
        textLayer.parentNode.removeChild(textLayer);
      }

      // Create new text layer container
      const newTextLayer = document.createElement('div');
      newTextLayer.className = 'text-layer';
      newTextLayer.style.width = `${viewport.width}px`;
      newTextLayer.style.height = `${viewport.height}px`;

      // Append text layer container to the parent element of the canvas
      canvas.parentNode.appendChild(newTextLayer);

      // Render the text content
      pdfjsLib.renderTextLayer({
        textContent: textContent,
        container: newTextLayer,
        viewport: viewport,
        textDivs: []
      });
    });

    // Output current page
    document.querySelector('#page-num').textContent = num;
  });

  // Hide the popup image
  popupImage.style.display = 'none';
};

// Check for pages rendering
const queueRenderPage = num => {
  if (pageIsRendering) {
    pageNumIsPending = num;
  } else {
    renderPage(num);
  }
};

// Show Prev Page
const showPrevPage = () => {
  if (pageNum <= 1) {
    return;
  }
  pageNum--;
  queueRenderPage(pageNum);
};

// Show Next Page
const showNextPage = () => {
  if (pageNum >= pdfDoc.numPages) {
    return;
  }
  pageNum++;
  queueRenderPage(pageNum);
};

// Get Document
pdfjsLib
  .getDocument(url)
  .promise.then(pdfDoc_ => {
    pdfDoc = pdfDoc_;

    document.querySelector('#page-count').textContent = pdfDoc.numPages;

    renderPage(pageNum);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // Display error
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'error';
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(err.message));
    document.querySelector('body').insertBefore(div, canvas);
    // Remove top bar
    document.querySelector('.top-bar').style.display = 'none';
  });



// Button Events
document.querySelector('#prev-page').addEventListener('click', showPrevPage);
document.querySelector('#next-page').addEventListener('click', showNextPage);
```

How do I acces text in pdf, so that I can copy it or addEventlistener to it?